# Calling Module of another Angular app in you angular app

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, ng-modules

Is it possible that i can lazy load a module attached to another angular app in the calling angular app?

Say i have Angular App A1 and A2
I want A1 as main angular app served to client. Now i want to add a new module folder to A2 ,build it and keep and call this module in A1 on request.

If possible this will solve my problem which was i wanted to add module folder while app is served and call it without rebuilding the whole app.

Note: Angular as in Angular 4

Comment: yes, it's possible.

Comment: @MukeshSoni any link or blog for that?

Comment: try ocLazyLoad.. https://oclazyload.readme.io/

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi but its just for angularjs

Comment: you asked for angularjs

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi well this community has alway edited my question that you dont write angular 2 or 4 , you write angular and for angular 1 you write angularJs